# What is mean by comparison of references and comparison of values?

Tags: string

Can anyone tell me when to use equals() and "==" operator?
I know that equals() method is used to compare the values of Strings. Also I know that "==" is used to check the references. What it exactly means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine two cars, for a moment.  Let's say they're a green Toyota Corolla and an orange Ferrari.  You want to compare them--are they similar?  Yes; they're both cars.  But, they have different properties.  Their values (literally and figuratively) are not equal, and when I talk about the Corolla, I'm definitely not talking about the Ferrari.  When I refer to one, I'm not referring to the other.

Now, imagine that I'm talking with you about a red Corolla.  You also have a red Corolla.  Neat!  We have the same car!  Except, they aren't *exactly* the same car, because they're two different cars.  They just happen to have the same value.  I can have mine painted and it won't change yours, or I could crash mine, and they won't have the same value.  Comparing our two cars would be like using the `equals()` method.  We could say they have the same value (until I crash mine, or change it some other way).

But, if we're each talking about a red Corolla, and it turns out I bought the Corolla from someone you sold yours to--hey, we're talking about the same Corolla!  We're actually referring to the same exact thing.  If I crash my Corolla, I've also crashed your (former) Corolla.  If I paint it, it's still the same car.  Checking whether we're talking about the *exact same thing* is reference equality.